# How to open iframe popup in parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, parent

Is there a way to open popup (which is in an iframe) in the parent window (the iframe and the parent are in diferent domains) using js/jquery

Answer (score 1):

The Browser security checks enforce that a couple of interactions from Iframes from different origin/domain to the host page is blocked.

To unblock, you need to use the sandbox attribute on the iframe to a value "allow-popups" to relax the restrictions.

There are other possible values you can set which you see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Be very careful with the values you set here except you completely trust the iframe domain.

Comment: I don't know if this can realy help , let me give you an example of what I want to do , I have a 300px*300px iframe and I want to show a popup(the modal is in the iframe) and I want it to pop in the parent window to take more place.

Comment: can you edit your question to post what you have done in or put it up in JSFiddle.